# The style doesn't apply when adding new class in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am self-studying Vue.js. I am using v-bind to add the highlight class to the span element, which is supposed to add newBorder style to the element, but the style doesn't get applied.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Intro to v-bind</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <style>
        .container {
            background: #cecece;
        }
        .newBorder {
            border: 5px solid yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">

        <img v-bind:src="'assets/images/look.jpg'" v-bind:alt="'illustration of the word -Look-'" v-bind:title="'Look'">
        <span v-bind:class="{loadClass,highlight}">
            look at me!
        </span>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                loadClass: 'container',
                highlight: 'newBorder'
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Appreciate it if you can point out my mistake.
Thanks

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: You could use `:class="{ loadClass: true, highlight: true }"`

Comment: Also, prefer using `new-border` to be a valid CSS property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the class binding the array syntax instead of object :

```
 <span v-bind:class="[loadClass,highlight]">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Intro to v-bind</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <style>
        .container {
            background: #cecece;
        }
        .newBorder {
            border: 5px solid yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">

        <img v-bind:src="'assets/images/look.jpg'" v-bind:alt="'illustration of the word -Look-'" v-bind:title="'Look'">
        <span v-bind:class="[loadClass,highlight]">
            look at me!
        </span>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                loadClass: 'container',
                highlight: 'newBorder'
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. Can you also refer me to a document for this? I don't understand Why the first method doesn't work. I was following the Vue.js documentation!

Comment: @NayerehRasuli https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes

Comment: You're welcome here the link https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax